# Excel 2010 Formula to make a count calculation based on two variables

Tags: excel-formula

Excel 2010 on Window 7

I'm struggling to find a formula which will count the number of open **and** overdue actions in a project tracker. This would be on the summary tab

The formula would need to to check the tab called 'actions' and make a count calculation based on the following variables:

1)  In each row in column A  the cell has 'open' populated  (options for this are 'open' and closed'

2) For each action that has 'open' specified in Column A it would also need to check the action due date in column J. If this date is overdue then this action would need to be counted.

I have tried a COUNTIF formula but it is only calculating overdue actions and ignoring if they are action is open or closed.

Any help you can provide will be much appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIFS` (with an `s` to support multiple conditions) - something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"open",B:B,"<="&TODAY())
```

Comment: just to add <="&TODAY will show actions overdue. What formula will show actions due in the next 3 days?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"open",B:B,"<="&(TODAY()+3))`

Comment: The COUNTIF formula works for the first scenario which is to calculate the number of OVERDUE actions. Formula will count the word 'open' in column A and if it is overdue (column J) =COUNTIFS(Actions!A6:A63,"open",Actions!J6:J63,"<="&TODAY()). The problem is using the formula to display actions due in the next 3 days. I use =COUNTIFS(Actions!A6:A63,"open",Actions!J6:J63,"<="&(TODAY()+3))but it seems to only be counting only the number of actions that are open and ignoring the date parameters. Can you see any issue with the second formula? Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: @Damian It looks fine - can you edit your question and add sample data so I can test?

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know how to add sample data

Comment: @Damian you click on the edit link below your question, and add an example of data to your question. Please also explain the result you get vs. what you expect.

Comment: This formula seemed to have worked: =COUNTIFS(Actions!A6:A63,"open",Actions!J6:J63,">"&(TODAY()),Actions!J6:J63,"<="&(TODAY()+3))